# How to render custom placeholder in react-grid-layout

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-grid-layout

Is there any way how to render custom placeholder (red item) in react-grid-layout?

I would like to render for example some `<img src...>` in this red placeholder.

I didn't found any informations about this in official docs (https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout).

Any tips?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can override the placeholder using the css class **.react-grid-placeholder**. This is part of the css styles that you import. So where you import the styles :

```
import 'react-grid-layout/css/styles.css';
import 'react-resizable/css/styles.css';

import './yourstyles.css';
```

and in yourstyles.css you can use an image as background like so:

```
.react-grid-item.react-grid-placeholder {
    background-color: background-image: url("imageURL")
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to render react component. Of course for my image example I can set the background image.. But in short, I would like to render content of card as a placeholder.

Comment: @vimov32802 For that you either make your own fork/implementation of the library or you can insert a position: "fixed" card with left,right,top,bottom css at the coordinates for the placeholder of class .react-grid-placeholder, like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element-relative-to-the-browser-window You can use MutationObserver to detect when the placeholder is on screen and add your fixed card or a plugin like this one https://github.com/pie6k/jquery.initialize